# No CurrentSessionContext configured!: ThreadLocalSessionContext.bind(session); isn't binding my session properly

Tags: hibernate, session, junit

I'm using Hibernate 4.0.1.Final.

I'm having trouble binding a session when testing my service.  I used `ThreadLocalSessionContext.bind(session)` to try and bind the session so that `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` returns a valid session but it isn't working.

Calling `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` produces an exception (below).  In my service class, I have:

```
public class OrganizationServiceImpl extends AbstractTransactionService implements OrganizationService {

public void saveOrganization(final String eodbId,
                             final String parentEodbId,
                             final String name,
                             final String description,
                             final String organizationType,
                             final String url,
                             final String stateAbbrev) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = startOperation();
        final State state = orgDao.findStateByAbbrev(stateAbbrev);

…

protected Session startOperation() throws HibernateException {
    final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    ThreadLocalSessionContext.bind(session);
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    return session;
}
```

Here's the JUnit test that invokes this service …

```
@Before
public void setupOrgServiceTest() { 
    Configuration config = new Configuration()
        .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:lyceaTestDb")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "sa")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "1")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "true")
        .setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider")
        .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop")
        .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
        .addAnnotatedClass(Organization.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(State.class); 
    final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
    sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    orgService = new OrganizationServiceImpl(sessionFactory);
}   // setupOrgSErviceTest

@Test
public void testSaveOrg() { 
    orgService.saveOrganization(testProps.getProperty("test.school.eodbId"),
                                testProps.getProperty("test.school.parent.eodbId"),
                                testProps.getProperty("test.school.name"), 
                                testProps.getProperty("test.school.description"), 
                                testProps.getProperty("test.school.org.type"), 
                                testProps.getProperty("test.school.url"), 
                                testProps.getProperty("test.school.state"));
}   // testSaveOrg
```

The exception I get when calling `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` is

```
org.myco.myproject.orgsclient.exceptions.DataAccessLayerException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    at org.myco.myproject.orgsclient.service.AbstractTransactionService.handleException(AbstractTransactionService.java:28)
    at org.myco.myproject.orgsclient.service.OrganizationServiceImpl.saveOrganization(OrganizationServiceImpl.java:42)
    at org.myco.myproject.orgsclient.service.OrganizationServiceTest.testSaveOrg(OrganizationServiceTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:881)
    at org.myco.myproject.orgsclient.dao.OrganizationDAOImpl.findStateByAbbrev(OrganizationDAOImpl.java:29)
    at org.myco.myproject.orgsclient.service.OrganizationServiceImpl.saveOrganization(OrganizationServiceImpl.java:30)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not specified the Hibernate property which tells the `SessionFactory` to use the `ThreadLocalSessionContext`.

```
setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread")
```

This means that when your `SessionFactory` is built Hibernate doesn't set the currentSessionContext. When you call `getCurrentSession()` there is nowhere for Hibernate to retrieve the current session from.

Other options are `jta` and `managed`.

Answer (score 2):

Add following property to hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```